# Datatables aaSorting is not sorting by the correct column

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I am trying to get a roster page to sort by player number onload. I plugged in aaSorting  and told it to sort the first column (the number) but it is sorting the second column (name). Can someone please tell me what I did wrong?

```
<style type="text/css">table.sortable th:not(.sorttable_sorted):not(.sorttable_sorted_reverse):not(.sorttable_nosort):after { 
    content: " \25B4\25BE" }
</style>

<!--<script src="/jscript/sorttable.js"></script>
--><script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".table-sortable").dataTable({
        aaSorting: [[0, 'asc']],
        bPaginate: false,
        bFilter: false,
        bInfo: false,
        bSortable: true,
        bRetrieve: true,
        aoColumnDefs: [
            { "aTargets": [ 0 ], "bSortable": true },
            { "aTargets": [ 1 ], "bSortable": true },
            { "aTargets": [ 2 ], "bSortable": true },
            { "aTargets": [ 3 ], "bSortable": true }
        ]
    }); 
});</script>





<table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1" class="sortable" id="roster" style="border-bottom:1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_sport_show_number) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_sport_show_number['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                <th class="style4, sortBy" style="width: 14px;"  data-sortType="numeric" id="number"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">#</span></th>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;" ><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Name</span></th>

            <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_show_class) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_show_class['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Class</span></th>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_show_position) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_show_position['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Position</span></th>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_show_height) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_show_height['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Height</span></th>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_show_weight) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_show_weight['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Weight</span></th>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_show_b_t) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_show_b_t['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">B/T</span></th>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_show_hometown) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_show_hometown['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Hometown</span></th>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_show_highschool) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_show_highschool['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Highschool</span></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $i=0; foreach($vars['athletes'] as $athlete): ?>
            <tr style="border:1; border-bottom:1px;">
                <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_sport_show_number) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_sport_show_number['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                    <td class="style4"  style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                        <?php echo $athlete->field_athleets_number['und'][0]['value'] ?>
                    </span></td>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                    <a href="#" href="" rel="imgtip[<?php echo $i; ?>] "><?php echo $athlete->title ?>
                </span></td>

                <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_show_class) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_show_class['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                    <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                        <?php echo ( $athlete->field_class['und'][0]['value'] ) ? $athlete->field_class['und'][0]['value'] : 'No Data' ?>
                    </span></td>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_show_position) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_show_position['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                    <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                        <?php echo ( $athlete->field_position['und'][0]['value'] ) ? $athlete->field_position['und'][0]['value'] : 'No Data' ?>
                    </span></td>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_show_height) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_show_height['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                    <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                        <?php echo ( $athlete->field_height['und'][0]['value'] ) ? $athlete->field_height['und'][0]['value'] : 'No Data' ?>
                    </span></td>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_show_weight) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_show_weight['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                    <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                        <?php echo ( $athlete->field_weight['und'][0]['value'] ) ? $athlete->field_weight['und'][0]['value'] : 'No Data' ?>
                    </span></td>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_show_b_t) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_show_b_t['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                    <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                        <?php echo ( $athlete->field_b_t['und'][0]['value'] ) ? $athlete->field_b_t['und'][0]['value'] : 'No Data' ?>
                    </span></td>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_show_hometown) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_show_hometown['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                    <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                        <?php echo ( $athlete->field_hometown['und'][0]['value'] ) ? $athlete->field_hometown['und'][0]['value'] : 'No Data' ?>
                    </span></td>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_show_highschool) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_show_highschool['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                    <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                        <?php echo ( $athlete->field_high_school_state['und'][0]['value'] ) ? $athlete->field_high_school_state['und'][0]['value'] : 'No Data' ?>
                    </span></td>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </tr>
        <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_sport_show_number) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_sport_show_number['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">#</span></th>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Name</span></th>

            <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_show_class) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_show_class['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Class</span></th>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_show_position) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_show_position['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Position</span></th>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_show_height) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_show_height['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Height</span></th>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_show_weight) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_show_weight['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Weight</span></th>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_show_b_t) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_show_b_t['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">B/T</span></th>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_show_hometown) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_show_hometown['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Hometown</span></th>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if( ! empty($vars['sport']->field_show_highschool) && 1 == $vars['sport']->field_show_highschool['und'][0]['value'] ): ?>
                <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Highschool</span></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
var st1 = new SortableTable(document.getElementById("roster"));
</script>
```

Page output

```
<h1 class="field-content h1 font-sizesmall ">Athletics: Baseball: Roster</h1>  </div>  </div>
    </div>






</div>  </div>
</div>
<div id="block-system-main" class="block block-system">


  <div class="content regularcontent">
    <div id="node-243" class="node node-page" about="/athletics/bb/roster" typeof="foaf:Document">




  <div class="content clearfix regularcontent">
    <div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded"><p>


<style type="text/css">table.sortable th:not(.sorttable_sorted):not(.sorttable_sorted_reverse):not(.sorttable_nosort):after { 
    content: " \25B4\25BE" }
</style>

<script src="/jscript/sorttable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#roster').dataTable( {
        "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]]
    } );
} );</script>





</p><table class="sortable" id="roster" style="border-bottom:1" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
                            <th class="style4, sortBy" style="width: 14px;" data-sorttype="numeric" id="number"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">#</span></th>

            <th sortdir="down" class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Name</span></th>

                            <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Class</span></th>

                            <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Position</span></th>

                            <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Height</span></th>

                            <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Weight</span></th>

                            <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">B/T</span></th>

                            <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Hometown</span></th>

                    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>























            <tr style="border:1; border-bottom:1px;">
                                    <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                        17                  </span></td>

                <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                    <a href="#" rel="imgtip[21] ">Aaron Woller              </a></span></td>

                                    <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                        SO                  </span></td>

                                    <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                        OF                  </span></td>

                                    <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                        6'0                 </span></td>

                                    <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                        170                 </span></td>

                                    <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                        R/R                 </span></td>

                                    <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                        St. Joseph, IL                  </span></td>

                            </tr><tr style="border:1; border-bottom:1px;">
                                    <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                        15                  </span></td>

                <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                    <a href="#" rel="imgtip[13] ">Austin Calhoun                </a></span></td>

                                    <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                        SO                  </span></td>

                                    <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                        OF                  </span></td>

                                    <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                        6'1                 </span></td>

                                    <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                        170                 </span></td>

                                    <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                        L/L                 </span></td>

                                    <td class="style4" style="vertical-align: top; width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">
                        Danville, IL                    </span></td>

                            </tr>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
                            <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">#</span></th>

            <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Name</span></th>

                            <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Class</span></th>

                            <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Position</span></th>

                            <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Height</span></th>

                            <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Weight</span></th>

                            <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">B/T</span></th>

                            <th class="style4" style="width: 14px;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;">Hometown</span>
```

Comment: What version of datatables you are using?

Comment: @Justinas How do I find that out?

Comment: Can you provide output html (taken in browser), not php source?

Comment: Look at the head of the .js file for a version.

Comment: @skobaljic added the output (minus some rows for space)

Comment: @isherwood I am not using a js file at the moment... it is commented out. but I was using the file from http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/#externalcall

Comment: If you're using DataTables, you're using a .js file.

Comment: I think the problem is that somehow it is not seeing the first column as the first column. I have set it to sort the first column on load and it is actually sorting the second column.

Comment: Open DataTables js file that you include in header and check comments, there must be version number.

Comment: @Justinas  that may be part of my problem because I don't have a datatables.js file. at least not that I included..might be a global thing, but the snippet of code I put in there I found on a site and it never said about including a datatables js file.....

Comment: @Justinas added the datatables file ..version DataTables 1.10.4 fromCDN but it is still sorting from the second column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following to the header

```
<link href="/jscript/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/jscript/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">table.sortable th:not(.sorttable_sorted):not(.sorttable_sorted_reverse):not(.sorttable_nosort):after { 
    content: " \25B4\25BE" }
</style>

<!--<script src="/jscript/sorttable.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function () {
  var coluna = $('#roster thead th.sorting_col').index('#roster thead th');
  var ordem  = $('#roster thead th.sorting_col').attr('data-sort');
  if(coluna == -1){coluna = 0;ordem  = 'asc';}
  $('#roster').DataTable({
    "paging":   false,
    "aaSorting": [[coluna,ordem,'number']]
  });
});</script>
```

Tweaked the javascript a bit and now it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you told, that you are using datatables 1.10.4 please double check documentation.

[Old documentation](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref) | [New documentation](http://datatables.net/reference)

As you can see, 1.10 parameters are rewritten and is changed from 1.9. You are using 1.10 version DataTables plugin, but using 1.9 version parameters

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#roster').dataTable({
        'order': [[ 0, 'asc' ]]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**stateSave Setting**

One thing to watch out for is the `stateSave` setting.  If this is true, the order is saved to localStorage.  So even if you change your javascript, a page reload will replace your new `order` with the old one.

**Clearing the Saved Order Setting**

To clear the old setting, you can manually delete the entry from localStorage or click the `reset` button if it's displayed.